# Replace values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,...,72 with 01, 02, 03,...,09, 10, 11, 12,...,72

Tags: r, string

I have a data which looks like this

```
X_STATE STATE_NAME
1       Alabama
2       Alaska
3       Arizona
.
.
9       Connecticut
10      Delaware
11      District of Columbia
```

The U.S state FIPS codes are in the from 01,02,03,...,09,10,11,...72 and not 1,2,3,...,9,10,11

The X_STATE variable is numeric

I am having some trouble in changing the the state codes from 1,2,3,...,9,10,11 to the correct version which is 01,02,03,...,09,10,11,...72.

My query is, how to make this transformation? Do we need to create some function(s)? I have tried multiple ways but no   avail. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: if you are reading in the data with, say, `read.csv`, and the codes are 01, 02, ... in your file, you can just read those columns as character strings and won't need to pad after the fact

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- 1:20    
sprintf("%02d", x)
#[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17"
#[18] "18" "19" "20"
```

Comment: Fyi, you don't need `c()` wrapping it